# Going from S-transform to eigenvalue density?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-matrices

Suppose we have a random matrix variable with the S-Transform below with $n>=1$

$$g(z)=\frac{1}{(1+z)^n}$$

What is the eigenvalue density around 0?

For $n=1$, this corresponds to Marchenko-Pastur law, hence for small eigenvalues $x$ we have

$$f(x)\sim\frac{1}{\pi  \sqrt{x}}$$

How do I get the corresponding expression for $n>1$?

Explicit formula of the density is given in 3.61 of Ipsen's [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf) but it's complex, I'm wondering if asymptotics can be determined directly from the S-transform.